# php artisan make:auth in laravel 5 have a bug

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel 5.2 after I use php artisan make:auth -> it download some package fine and I also can open the page like this:

[image: dashboard]

but after I click the link for login, it always error like this:

[image: Error after click the link]

Answer (score 0):

at kernal.php [ app/Http/Kernal.php ]

Move StartSession::class and ShareErrorsFromSession::class to protected

Eg:

```
  protected $middleware = [ 

       \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,          
       \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class, 

  ];
```